# Single CRUD controller for different models and views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 project with Entity Framework.

I'm creating an Administration page with **different subpages**. These pages are **used just to configure properties of different models**. All my **views are strongly typed**, so every view sends back to the controller an object of some type. Since controller performs the same actions for every model and view and I have many models, **I would like to maintain only one single controller without copypasting it, changing only methods signatures and some other stuff**.

I always have a **category variable** set through post requests to save the subpage i'm currently in and to detect which model's data I need to read or insert/delete. I have no problems with read method:

```
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string category)
        {
            ViewBag.Category = category;
            return Json(_cat.Category(category).ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

It calls a Category method which has a dictionary and basing on the category var it uses repository to read the data of needed model and to send it back to the controller. Simple.

But with Create/Update/Delete controllers I can't do the same without copypasting. Here's the simplified example:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
            string category,
            MeansAssessment meansassessment = null,
            EthinicOrigin ethinicorigin = null)
        {
            ViewBag.Category = category;
            switch (category)
            {
                case "MeansAssessments":
                    if (meansassessment != null && ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        _meansAssessmentsRepository.Update(meansassessment);
                    }
                    break;
                case "EthinicOrigins":
                    if (ethinicorigin != null && ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        _ethinicOriginsRepository.Update(ethinicorigin);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
        }
```

As you can see, I have to put objects of all model types I have (there's 20+ of them) into the methods signature and to call the right repository using switch.

I would like to do smth like creating some basic class and working with it. I tried it in different was, but no luck.

Any help and ideas will be greatly appreciated!